# Why doesn't stringification work outside macro in C++ VS2017

Tags: c++, macros

While strinizing macro paramaters in C++ VS2017, I realized it only works for macro parameters, not ordinary macros:

```
#define PRINT(FOO) cout << #FOO; // OK
#define BAR blah
cout << #BAR;                    // error C2162
```

The last line above for #BAR generates "error C2162: expected macro formal parameter." I know I can get around the error by passing BAR as a macro parameter but I'm wondering why this isn't supported? I'd be surprised if there was non-parameter way to get this to work, but if anyone has one I'm all ears.

Comment: The `#` operator is only defined to work with macro parameters.  See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace

Comment: i don't think you can, you should just #define BAR as litteral string.

Comment: @Richard, thanks for the link. It confirmed what I'm seeing. My other question was simply Why? Seems like something the preprocessor should be able to do.

Comment: If so then #if would become "if", etc.  Questions about the origins of parts of the language which date back to pre-standardisation days rarely have a definite answer.

Comment: @Richard, makes sense. thx